# Ошибка The type or namespace name ''..." could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

При добавлении нового файла(класса) в workspace в Visual Studio Code возникает ошибка:

> The type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?).

В файле `Item` не подключаются директивы `using`. При этом, если я поменяю название `Item` на `Zitem`, то есть файл окажется после класса `Program`, то ошибка пропадёт. Почему? Как это исправить?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: То есть у вас в Item.cs лежит класс с именем "Item" и находится в том же пространстве имён? Проверьте ещё раз, что всё так. Иначе, честно говоря, я не вижу возможных проблем. Баг IDE получается какой-то.

Comment: Именно так. Класс Item.cs в том же пространстве имён. Дело в assembly referencies, но я не понимаю как добавить ссылку на этот файл вручную. Кстати, ошибка пропадает, если я удаляю этот файл и создаю класс Item.cs in new file через Intellisense.

Comment: А старый файл откуда взялся? Вы можете визуально отличить русские и латинские буквы - "а", "о", "е"? Я - нет.

Comment: А Intellisense не предлагает так же решение этой же проблемы? Типа добавить эти ссылки автоматом? А другие такие же классы пробовали или проблема именно в этом?  А если в созданные автоматом класс перенести весь код из вашего класса,то всё работает? @Igor тему говорит...

Comment: Старый файл взялся вот как: ПКМ по области на первой картинке => New File. Раскладки я не путал) В общем случае, если я добавлю любой файл таким образом, и он будет находится раньше по алфавиту, чем Program.cs, то ничего работать не будет.

Comment: Какой namespace у класса Item? И это работает для любого нового файла, который раньше по алфавиту? А если не Zitem, а Aitem будет работать?

Answer (score 0):

Пространство имен не должно совпадать с названием класса. 
Пространство имен Items
класс Item
и тогда new Items.Item() без проблем будет

Comment: А откуда вы взяли информацию, что там Item namespace? Проект называется Arch, а файл лежит в корне, а не в папке Item. Так что скорее всего там полный путь Arch.Item. Если обратного не укажет автор.